# Play video frames one by one using gstreamer pipeline

Tags: video, gstreamer, frame-rate

How to play video frames one by one using `gstreamer` pipeline.

I don't see any options for this in `gst-play` application, and I also tried with capsfilter in below pipeline, got no luck.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.264 ! h264parse ! omx_h264dec ! video/x-raw, width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12, framerate=1/1 ! videosink
```

I know that `videorate` could lower the framerate by dropping frames. But I don't want frames to be dropped.

Comment: there is no ready made plugin to do that, you can have simple pipeline (gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.264 ! h264parse ! omx_h264dec ! appsink)  --> opencv to display the image/ use another pipileine to display the image. (quick serach https://coherentmusings.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/extracting-frame-from-a-gstreamer-pipeline-and-displaying-it-with-opencv/)

Comment: There is `gst_event_new_step` for this purpose. But you need to create small app yourself as none default ones expose this functionality.